# Open outlook to inbox by default

Tags: macos, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

Using Outlook 2016 for Mac. Upon launching Outlook it loads into whatever folder I quit the program in, which was fine as I usually closed while viewing the inbox anyways.

However, all of a sudden when I close the Outlook window (not quit the program just close the window) it opens back up into whatever folder is 2 under the inbox. I thought it was first an issue with my subfolders so I got rid of those and now it loads into deleted items. This happens no matter what folder I am viewing when I close the window.

How can I get Outlook to always load into the inbox?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Mac, but in Windows there is an option for this under Advanced:

[image]

Comment: Office 2016 on OS X and Office 2016 are not identical.  You should confirm this option exists for the OS X version of Office 2016